# Angular 4 integration with Struts 2

Tags: angular, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am new to Angular 4. Is it possible to integrate Angular 4 with Struts and Hibernate ?

If yes, then where to keep `web.xml`, JSP files, Hibernate etc. Where to keep struts jar?

Any example code or documentation link will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2/4 app you develop in the separate project or module, probably even using separate IDE. The backend might use any technology that has a web API endpoints.

If the backend is Struts then endpoints should be mapped via the action mapper.

Also Struts doesn't work with Hibernate without integration, you should integrate Struts with Hibernate, or Spring with Hibernate and then integrate Struts with Spring.