# Integrate angular 4 with struts 2

Tags: java, angular, routes, struts2

Need suggestions on approach in migrating a existing struts to angular piece by piece. I want to keep both struts and angular and convert to angular.i explored other posts on this topic about passing data back and forth but I need a way to not touch the action mapper completely. Need to have routing control detect path and pass between angular and struts.

P.S - I am newbie to posting in stack overflow. So please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45863394/573032

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the existing application and the new angular application side by side?

1. Identify modules in existing application.
2. Implement a module with struts rest api https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/
3. Implement angular for that module

You can set the base href in angular to

> applicationname.foo.bar/module1
>
> applicationname.foo.bar/module2
>
> applicationname.foo.bar/module3

but this way you will have multiple angular projects and that will be a pain.
The upside is that you can now reimplement module1, module2, module3 separately.

I'm not sure how your existing struts application can handle `applicationname.foo.bar/module1` but not `applicationname.foo.bar/module2` though.

I think it will help if you expand on your question to clarify what you need.